# ReadWrite & ReadOnly datagrid with binding to shared source, resulting in ReadWrite not proper ReadWrite?

Tags: wpf, binding, wpfdatagrid, readonly-attribute

I found something strange:
I have a form with two datagrids with binding to the same collection.
Depending on the order of the datagrids in the Xaml the behavior is different.

This works as expected (the extra row for adding is present):

```
<DockPanel>
    <DockPanel DockPanel.Dock="Right">
        <Label Content="ReadOnlyView" DockPanel.Dock="Top"/>
        <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Persons}" IsReadOnly="True" />
    </DockPanel>
    <DockPanel>
        <Label Content="EditorView" DockPanel.Dock="Top" />
        <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Persons}" IsReadOnly="False" CanUserAddRows="True" />
    </DockPanel>
</DockPanel>
```

Arranging the xaml this way is what confuses me (no extra row for adding)

```
<DockPanel>
    <DockPanel>
        <Label Content="EditorView" DockPanel.Dock="Top" />
        <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Persons}" IsReadOnly="False" CanUserAddRows="True" />
    </DockPanel>
    <DockPanel DockPanel.Dock="Right">
        <Label Content="ReadOnlyView" DockPanel.Dock="Top"/>
        <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Persons}" IsReadOnly="True" />
    </DockPanel>
</DockPanel>
```

Below is the dummy ViewModel I used for this:

```
public class PersonsViewModel
{
    public PersonsViewModel()
    {
        Persons = new ObservableCollection<Person>
                    {
                        new Person {Name = "Johan"},
                        new Person {Name = "Dave"},
                    };
    }

    public ObservableCollection<Person> Persons { get; private set; }
}

public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

My question is what is the reason for this behavior?

Answer (score 2):

An excellent question Johan! My guess would be that since you are not explicitly providing it with a `CollectionViewSource`, the automatically generated cvs by `DataGrid` is shared between the two as you are referring to the same source.

Hence the last setting wins when you issue two `IsReadOnly` assignments and being a shared source, both `DataGrid` show you the same effect.

In order to confirm my guess I've used this code and the `DataGrids` behave as you would expect when you offer them explicit `CollectionViewSource` to work with.

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
        <CollectionViewSource Source="{Binding Persons}" x:Key="cvs1" />
        <CollectionViewSource Source="{Binding Persons}" x:Key="cvs2" />
    </Window.Resources>
    <DockPanel>
        <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource ResourceKey=cvs1}}" IsReadOnly="False" CanUserAddRows="True" />
        <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource ResourceKey=cvs2}}" IsReadOnly="True" />
    </DockPanel>
</Window>
```

EDIT: Further testing indicates the behaviour can just be described as odd! I cannot explain why this produces three readonly DGs

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Persons}" IsReadOnly="True" />
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Persons}" IsReadOnly="False" />
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Persons}" IsReadOnly="True" />
```

but this produces alternating readonly and editable DG:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Persons}" IsReadOnly="True" />
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Persons}" IsReadOnly="False" />
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Persons}" IsReadOnly="True" />
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Persons}" IsReadOnly="False" />
```

So I guess the above CVS is best described as workaround for this odd behaviour, so you can achieve what you actually want.

EDIT 2: After even more combinations of true false, the only consistent thing i've noticed is that if the Last `IsReadOnly` in `DataGrid` is set to True, all other `DataGrids` become readonly. But if the last one is set to false, then all other DataGrids behave according to their own IsReadOnly setting. This behvaiour may possibly be due to this [MSDN bit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid.isreadonly.aspx)

```
If a conflict exists between the settings at the DataGrid, column,
or cell levels, a value of true takes precedence over a value of false.
```